# SQL Query: Need to output two columns with values based on conditional data

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been reviewing some related posts, and cannot seem to get this working in Oracle SQL and needed some guidance. I am working with some data where I want to output values from the same table and columns in a custom column based on conditional data.

Example Data:

```
corp_acct   Subscriber_id  MAX_EXTENSIONS    
10001       90000          1   
10002       90001          1  
10003       90002          2  
10004       90003          3  
10005       90004          1  
10006       90005          2  
10007       90005          1
```

In this example, I want to output two columns of corp_acct one as lesser and one as more where in the first column I want to output all corp_acct with max_extensions = 1 and in the second column I want all corp_acct that => 2

Example output

```
lesser      more  
10001       10003             
10002       10004            
10005       10006  
10007
```

I don't want to create any new tables and only want to do a select statement based on outputting these two columns, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when max_extensions = 1 then corp_acct end) as col1,
       max(case when max_extensions > 1 then corp_acct end) as col2       
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by case when max_extensions = 1 then 1 else 2 end order by corp_acct) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```